# Split string and added space in between string

Tags: string, function

I have string say that has 500 characters at a strech without anyspaces in between, I want to introduce space in between that string for every 50 characters, can anyone help me out?? how to do this using javascript or jquery or useing c#. Im using MVC3 in .net4 framework with SQL 2010.

Answer (score 1):

read the first 50 chars, add a space, read the next 50, add a space .... i would use a loop.